# Unable to capture cURL output in a text file?

Tags: shell, curl

I am using this command to capture time taken by cURL command:

```
 time curl -v -k http://10.164.128.232:8011/oam/server/HeartBeat >> abc.txt
```

This leaves abc.txt blank. I further tried this:

```
time curl -v -k http://10.164.128.232:8011/oam/server/HeartBeat 2>> bcde.txt
```

I was expecting this command to write complete console output on my text file, but it din't capture time in bcde.txt.

I am unable to find a way using which I can capture cURL's output alongside time taken by it.

Please assist me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(time curl -v -k http://10.164.128.232:8011/oam/server/HeartBeat) 2>> abc.txt

This worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

The time command may think that the redirection is part of the command being timed.  In that case, you can get past it with grouping:

(time curl -v -k http://10.164.128.232:8011/oam/server/HeartBeat) >> abc.txt